# Saving Data to SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml

I am completely new to Windows 8 apps. I am trying to save data from my application to an SQLite database. I am writing in C#/XAML. I have the database set up and it is storing hard-coded data, but I need to to save data from pictures which are saved locally. I have the buttons set up on my MainPage.xaml.cs page, but they have no functionality.

When I run this it saves the data to my SQLite database, but I cannot get it to work with a button on my application. Is there a way to call this function with a button?

```
public void SaveData()
{
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
    {
        // Empty the TableImages tables 
        //db.DeleteAll<TableImages>();

        //Add New Image
        var newImage = new TableImages()
                       {
                           //ID = newImage.Id,
                           imagePath = "c:\\My Images",
                           imageName = "testImage.jpg",
                           imageDate = "6/6/2014",
                           //binaryLargeImage = "Windows Store app"
                       };

        db.Insert(newImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe we could be more helpful with a more precise error than "I cannot get it to work". Please clarify the problem. Usually problems may come from provider and connection string, have you set up everything ?

Comment: Well basically I am looking for a way to call SaveData in my button on my MainPage. Is there a way to call this code above into a button?

Comment: can't  you just put a button and have the click event call the SaveData() ??? Put a button on the MainPage and double click on the button then add your code..